# Custom citations in text

Tags: bibliographies

I want to customize the citation in the text of my LaTeX document. Currently when citing, only **[1, p.123]** is stated when citing. Is it possible to introduce a new command so the citation inserts **(Simpson 1998: p.123)** as the source reference?

When searching for the customization of bibliographies only the style of the bibliography (list of sources like books, proceedings etc.) is considered, not the shorthand in the text...

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\title{\LaTeX}
\date{}
\begin{document}

This thesis bases on the theoretical work of Simpson \cite[p.123]{Simpson}.

\begin{thebibliography}{50}
        \bibitem{Simpson} Homer J. Simpson. \textsl{Mmmmm...donuts}. Evergreen Terrace Printing Co., Springfield, SomewhereUSA, 1998
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Citation text]

Comment: bibliography styles or `biblatex` are working only with `bib` files. Do you have one and the example shows only the required result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `biblatex` so you can change the citestyle to `authoryear`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Simpson,
  title = {Mmmmm...donuts},
  publisher = {Evergreen Terrace Printing Co.},
  year = {1998},
  author = {Homer J. Simpson},
  address = {Springfield, SomewhereUSA}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} % add colon after year

\begin{document}    

This thesis bases on the theoretical work of Simpson \parencite[123]{Simpson}.    

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still don't have written the whole `thebibliography` environment manually, it's best to switch to using BibTeX or better yet `biblatex` as the other answer says.

If your bibliography is already in place, simple changes will make it work for an author-year style:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
\title{\LaTeX}
\date{}
\begin{document}

This thesis bases on the theoretical work of Simpson \cite[p.~123]{Simpson}.

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Simpson(1998)]{Simpson} Homer J. Simpson. \textsl{Mmmmm...donuts}. 
  Evergreen Terrace Printing Co., Springfield, SomewhereUSA, 1998

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

You have to load `natbib` as shown and add the optional argument to `\bibitem` in the form

```
<author list>(<year)
```

without any space between the author list and the parenthesis. For instance, two authors could be

```
\bibitem[Gilbert and Sullivan(1878)]{pinafore}
  W. S. Gilbert and A. Sullivan, \emph{H.M.S. Pinafore}, London, Opera Comique, 1878.
```